# after bundle install error kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On remote server I downloaded project. In root directory project run bundle install. Display error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

I check current ruby version. is

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

I dont undestand why this error. But think, its becose i removed rvm from machine and manual installed ruby 2.3.1 without ruby manager. Help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps, you missed `install gem bundler`, try to install it first:

```
gem install bundler
```

then run `bundle install` again